# How to number equations as (item-num.number-in-item)

Tags: equations, numbering, itemize

I would like to number equations in items in this form: `(item-num.number-in-item)` where `item-num` is the item number (first item is 1, second item is 2) and `number-in-item` is the number within an item. When entering a new item, the `number-in-item` is automatically reset to 0. For example, for latex code:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[\bf 1.] This is item 1. This is item 1.
\begin{equation} a=b+c \end{equation}
This is item 1. This is item 1.This is item 1. This is item 1.This is item 1. This is item 1.This is item 1. This is item 1.This is item 1. This is item 1.
\begin{equation} d=e+f \end{equation}
This is item 1. This is item 1

\item[\bf 2.] This is item 2. This is item 2.This is item 2.
\begin{equation} g=h+i \end{equation}
This is item 2. This is item 2
\end{itemize}
```

, the output should be:

> **1.** This is item 1. This is item 1.
>
> ```
>          a=b+c            (1.1)
> ```
>
> This is item 1. This is item 1.This is item 1. This is item 1.This is item 1. This is item 1.This is item 1. This is item 1.This is item 1. This is item 1.
>
> ```
>          d=e+f            (1.2)
> ```
>
> **2.** This is item 2. This is item 2.This is item 2.
>
> ```
>          g=h+i            (2.1)
> ```
>
> This is item 2. This is item 2

How to write latex to realize such a numbering? Thank you.

Comment: Normally the item number is  `\thenumi`, but that depends on which packages you add.  One can reset the equation number using `\@addtoreset{equation}{enumi}` and redefine `\theequation` or just use `\tag`.

Comment: @John Kormylo: I was told "! Undefined control sequence." Which package is `\thenumi` in?

Comment: `itemize` doesn't assign item numbers; `enumerate` *does* assign numbers.  This would likely be easier with the `enumitem` package.

Comment: @barbara beeton: I changed to `enumerate` and added `\usepackage{enumitem}` and `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theenumi.\arabic{equation}}`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `\numberwithin` command from `amsmath` to number the `equation` counter within the `enumi` counter, which is the counter from the items in the enumerate environment. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\numberwithin{equation}{enumi}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries\arabic*.}, ref=\arabic*]
\item This is item 1. This is item 1.
\begin{equation} a=b+c \end{equation}
This is item 1. This is item 1.This is item 1. This is item 1.This is item 1. This is item 1.This is item 1. This is item 1.This is item 1. This is item 1.
\begin{equation} d=e+f \end{equation}
This is item 1. This is item 1
\item This is item 2. This is item 2.This is item 2.
\begin{equation} g=h+i \end{equation}
This is item 2. This is item 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Vincent. I noticed that you removed `[\bf 1.]`, `[\bf 2.]`. Is there any way to make the item number bold (but the `item-num` in equation number is not bold)?

Comment: Yes of course! It can be done using the great ``enumitem`` package. Sorry, I wanted to include that at first, but I guess I forgot.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Except for itemize not being numbered, everything worked fine.  No packages needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{equation}{enumi}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theenumi.\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item test
\begin{equation} x=a \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x=b \end{equation}
\item test
\begin{equation} x=c \end{equation}
\begin{equation} x=d \end{equation}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```